# issue while using JsPdf AutoTable setting newline on 'd' and other characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I' using jsPDF with AutoTable in my WebSite, and there is an issue when i'm exporting my Table to PDF.

When the PDF contains 'd' letter in the string in a column, after the 'd' jsPDF will set a newline by breaking a word and by making the PDF unreadable.

There were other cases even with other characters like number '2'.

Is there a way to fix it?

Here is how it looks like when exported:
[image]

While the text breaked was:

```
antipasto con gnocco patate  + spergola
bimbi verdi + tagliatella ragù
tortello verde + riso
misto carni arrosto con patate e padleda
Alessandra cioccolatina con smarties
```

My function where i make the jsPDF looks like this:

```
function PDF(id, stat) {
    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4', true);
    var table = '#' + id;
    var text = 'Prenotazioni del ' + moment($("#day").attr('data-giorno')).format('DD MMMM YYYY');

    doc.setFontSize(18);
    doc.text($('#titlepdf').val(), 14, 22);
    doc.setFontSize(11);
    doc.setTextColor(100);

    doc.text(text, 14, 35);

    doc.autoTable({
        html: table,
        startY: 45,
        showHead: 'firstPage',
        includeHiddenHtml: true,
        columnStyles: {
            0: {
                columnWidth: 80
            },
            1: {
                columnWidth: 50
            },
            2: {
                columnWidth: 50
            },
            3: {
                columnWidth: 50
            },
            4: {
                columnWidth: 100
            },
            5: {
                columnWidth: 200
            }
        },
        headStyles: {
            fillColor: [189, 21, 63],
            fontSize: 10,
            theme: 'grid'
        },
        styles: {
            overflow: 'linebreak',
            columnWidth: 'wrap',
            font: 'arial',
            fontSize: 10,
            cellPadding: 8,
            overflowColumns: 'linebreak'
        }
    });

    doc.text(stat, 14, doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + 15);

    doc.save('prenotazione.pdf');
}
```

Here is the table:

```
<table id="tableGiorno" class="table table-hover" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 12px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Orario</th>
            <th>Tavolo</th>
            <th>Coperti</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="bodyGiorno">
        <tr data-tavolo="34">
            <td>Igor</td>
            <td>14:00</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <a onclick="event.stopImmediatePropagation();" href="tel:" rel="nofollow"></a>
            </td>
            <td>Da oggi sono stato fedele grazie alla lorem</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you make a snippet?

Comment: Where do You get the file? This seems an encoding issue, because `0x0d` is the carriage return - moreover `0x200d` and `0x200a` are also specified inside the **xref** table for line endings. Please, check the character encoding of Your files and documents...

Comment: try putting the text inside a <div> with <p>tags

`<div>
<p>antipasto con gnocco patate  + spergola</p>
<p>bimbi verdi + tagliatella ragù</p>
<p>tortello verde + riso</p>
<p>misto carni arrosto con patate e padleda</p>
<p>Alessandra cioccolatina con smarties</p>
</div>`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc i've added the table with the data

Comment: @NathanTM i'd give it a try

Comment: @NathanTM just tried and even with p i have that issue

Comment: @deblocker the webpage has the encoding set to utf8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by changing the jsPDF version to the last one (2.3.1) i was using the 1.5.3.

Comment: Is there a migration guide? I'm migrating 1.5.3 to 2.3.1 but it has broken a lot and not a migration guide in sight.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins i don't think so, i had to change all library files and had to implement again all my jsPDF functions, actually it didn't took too much for me as i used it in two tables, you can make a new question about the errors it gives to you after the migration

Answer (score -1):

This issue is precisely for the lower versions fo the jsPDF. If you upgrade to the latest version i.e. >(2.3), the issue will get resolved.